# Problem with state in a TextField - Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, programación-móvil, jetpack-compose

Cuando agrego una película no tengo ningún problema con el estado de los elementos componibles. Pero cuando edito una película (tengo la misma lógica para cambiar el estado tanto al editar como al crear una película), escribir con el teclado cambia el valor llamando a onChangeName() y lo vuelve a llamar. Por ejemplo:

(1) Original: Joker, Modificado: Joke
(2) Original: Joker, v: Joker

No entiendo porque se llama 2 veces el método, por ejemplo, onChangeName. Ocurre con todos los campos del formulario.

Demostración vídeo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pvUi02NQIQeK5rM1enca5Jcnl7y45Fho/view?usp=sharing

```
HiltViewModel
class MovieFormViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val movieRepository: MovieRepository,
    private val genderRepository: GenderRepository,
    private val movieValidator: MovieValidator
): ViewModel() {
    class MovieViewModelException(message: String) : Exception(message)

    var editingContactExistingState: Boolean = false
        private set
    var genreList: List<String> by mutableStateOf(emptyList())
    var movieState by mutableStateOf(MovieUiState())
        private set
    var movieValidationState by mutableStateOf(MovieValidationUiState())
        private set

    init {
        loadGenders()
    }

    fun setMovie(movieId: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val movie: Movie = movieRepository.get(movieId) ?: throw MovieViewModelException("El id $movieId no existe en la base de datos")
            movieState = movie.toMovieUiState()
            movieValidationState = movieValidator.validate(movieState)
            editingContactExistingState = true
        }
    }

    fun clearMovieState() {
        editingContactExistingState = false
        movieState = MovieUiState()
        movieValidationState = MovieValidationUiState()
    }

    private suspend fun getGenders(): List<String> = genderRepository.get().map { it.name }
    private fun loadGenders() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            genreList = getGenders()
        }
    }

    fun onMovieFormEvent(event: MovieFormEvent) {
        when(event) {
            is MovieFormEvent.OnChangeFoto -> {

            }
            is MovieFormEvent.OnChangeName -> {
                movieState = movieState.copy(name = event.name)
                movieValidationState = movieValidationState.copy(
                    nameValidation = movieValidator.nameValidator.validate(movieState.name)
                )
            }
            is MovieFormEvent.OnChangeDescription -> {
                movieState = movieState.copy(description = event.description)
                movieValidationState = movieValidationState.copy(
                    validationDescription = movieValidator.validatorDescription.validate(movieState.description)
                )
            }
            is MovieFormEvent.OnChangeGenders -> {
                val newGenders: MutableList<String> = movieState.genders.toMutableList()
                if(newGenders.contains(event.gender)) newGenders.remove(event.gender) else newGenders.add(event.gender)
                movieState = movieState.copy(genders = newGenders)
                movieValidationState = movieValidationState.copy(
                    gendersValidation = movieValidator.gendersValidator.validate(movieState.genders.joinToString(""))
                )
            }
            is MovieFormEvent.OnChangeTrailerLink -> {
                movieState = movieState.copy(trailerLink = event.trailerLink)
                movieValidationState = movieValidationState.copy(
                    trailerValidation = movieValidator.trailerValidator.validate(movieState.trailerLink)
                )
            }
            is MovieFormEvent.OnChangePrice -> {
                movieState = movieState.copy(price = event.price)
                movieValidationState = movieValidationState.copy(
                    priceValidation = movieValidator.priceValidator.validate(movieState.price)
                )
            }
            else -> {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creo que deberías usar `MutableStateFlow` o `LiveData`

Comment: No funciona Mateo